# GridLayout. Установить ширину ячейки программно

Tags: android

Создаю программно три элимента в GridLayout:

```
private List<TextView> editTextList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<EditText> editTextList2 = new ArrayList<>();

llt = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

TextView  editTxt = new TextView(this);


       // editTxt.setLayoutParams(100,130);
        editTxt.setLayoutParams(lButtonParams);
        editTextList.add(i, editTxt);
        llt.addView(editTxt);

        EditText  editTxt2 = new EditText(this);
        editTxt2.setLayoutParams(lButtonParams);
        editTextList2.add(i, editTxt2);
        // editTxt2.setGravity(FILL);
        llt.addView(editTxt2);


        Button btn =  new Button(this);
      //  btn.setLayoutParams(lButtonParams);
        btn.setId(i);
        btn.setText("click!");
        llt.addView(btn);
```

Но проблема в том, что добавленные элементы сдвигаются в левую сторону. Как их выравнять? Растянуть их на всю длину GridLayout? Если добавлять в xml файл, то выравнивается автоматом по самому длинному элементу.

Пробовал эксперементировать с

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lButtonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Результат остался тот же.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос можно считать закрытым. Мой просчёт. Всё нормально центрирует автоматом, проблема была в том, что заполнял нолями, а по ним и устанавливалась ширина остальных колонок. Всем спасибо за внимание и помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понел вопрос но можно дать им центровку `gravity = center;` или добавить отступ от левого края `MarginLeft`

Comment: Надо что бы эти три ячейки были растянуты на всю длину GridLayout. А сейчас они сбиваются к левому краю.И остается свободное место. Как тут картинки прикреплять так и не понял.

Comment: ты указал порядок котором они будут отображатся ?я чтот неижу

Comment: Отображаются в том порядке в котором и добавляются.